# What's the meaning of "иде же несть печали и воздыхания"?

Tags: значения

Reading Ivan Bunin's short story Чаша жизни, I stumbled upon this phrase:

"А когда ударила по сердцам скорбно ликующая песнь о той обители, иде же несть печали и воздыхания,"

I guess that иде=где and несть=нет. Is my guess correct?

Are these words Old Church slavonicisms?

Comment: It's actually not Russian, but Church Slavonic.

Comment: Alexey Veleshk it can hardly be called a separate language :>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second part is a reference to *Со святыми упокой*, a [kontakion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kontakion) (liturgical hymn) sung at the memorial service.

*Идѣже* (it's a single word) is Church Slavonic for *где* "where", or, more precisely, *в которой* "in which".

This word formation pattern (adding the particle *же* to pronouns and deictics), in general, is quite confusing to Russian speakers: words like *имже, еяже, егоже* (*которым, которую, которого*) etc. sound very close to the Russian phrases *им же, её же, его же* which mean completely different things.

*Нѣсть* indeed means "there is no".

Comment: I would add that, while being an Old Church slavonicism, in the modern Russian Нѣсть is still used in the often-cited Biblical paraphrase "Нeсть пророка в отечестве своём" (where we, of course, type "e" instead of "ѣ").  This is the last example of use of this word in the modern speech. Much more seldom - and only from highly educated or snobbish people - you will hear things like "Нeсть ему прощения" or "Нeсть ему воздаяния", but this sounds obsolete and almost pretentious.

Comment: @Michael_1812: _несть числа, несть конца_

Comment: Sure. This falls under the auspices of my example.

Comment: [Here](https://foma.ru/svyatyimi-upokoy-hriste-dushi-rab-tvoih.html) they say that this prayer is sung during *funeral service* (отпевание, or more precisely, погребение). It *might* be sung during *memorial service* as well, but is optional in that case.

Comment: @Michael_1812 I have only seen the phrase in form нет пророка в своём отечестве, that is in Russian form.

Comment: @Anixx This is the original saying still in use in the religious practice: "Несть пророк без чести, токмо в отечествии своем и в дому своем." (Евангелие от Матфея 13:57)